# Pace.js Implementation

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, pace.js

Am trying to setup pace.js. To show progress bar during upload and download. Intially am setting the startOnPageLoad: false, so it will no appear during page load. While clicking download or upload am calling the Pace.Restart(). And loading bar showed up. But the loading animation is finished way before the file completely downloads or uploads.   How can i configure the timing to show the progress bar using pace.js?